# babel polyfill catches my errors in place of letting bubble them

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs, babel-polyfill, raygun

I'm using *raygun* to keep track of my front-end errors. Raygun exploits the EventError by hooking on the `window.onerror` property. So far so good.

My application is written in ES6 and it uses generators. I use *babel* to write ES6 web browser compliant code and *webpack* to bundle it. Since I'm using `generators` I also import Babel `polyfill` in my HTML along with my `entry chunk`. I'm not importing it into my application because the HTML page could load other applications, which in turn could try to run the polyfill. That way, just a polyfill instance is run.

```
<script src="/container/lib/polyfill.js"></script>
<script src="/container/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="/container/myApp.js"></script>
```

To make sure `window.onerror` works, I had first wrote my own error handler (well, I had copied it from MDN):

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
    var string = msg.toLowerCase();
    var substring = "script error";
    if (string.indexOf(substring) > -1){
        alert('Script Error: See Browser Console for Detail');
    } else {
        var message = [
            'Message: ' + msg,
            'URL: ' + url,
            'Line: ' + lineNo,
            'Column: ' + columnNo,
            'Error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error)
        ].join(' - ');

        alert(message);
    }

    return false;
};
```

so, by running my code, I would expect a wonderful vintage alert.

Unfortunately, what I get is a message on my error log, but window.onerror hook does not catch it:

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: test
Analisi dello stack:
runApp@webpack:///../index.js?:86:11
initSteps$@webpack:///../index.js?:161:21
tryCatch@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:6151:37
invoke@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:6442:22
defineIteratorMethods/</prototype[method]@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:6203:16
resume@webpack:////Users/matteo/Documents/em3/container/web_src/lib/utils.js?:25:9
initSteps$/<@webpack:///../index.js?:148:25
run@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:3911:22
notify/<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:3924:28
flush@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1209:9
MutationCallback*[64]</module.exports@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1228:5
[198]<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:3837:26
s@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:246
s/<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:305
[295]<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:6017:1
s@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:246
s/<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:305
[1]</<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:5:1
[1]<@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:2:2
s@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:246
e@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:425
@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:1:11
```

while if I move my `throw new Error('test');` outside my generator function, I get the expected alert. How can I avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like errors thrown inside your generator happen from a promise context, and unhandled promise rejections are handled differently from uncaught sync errors.

To catch an uncaught promise rejection you can use the following, for example:

```
window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (event) {
  console.warn("WARNING: Unhandled promise rejection. Reason: "
               + event.reason);
});
```

With some older polyfills or older native promises you may have to do the following instead:

```
window.onunhandledrejection = function(event) { ...};
```

Comment: did you notice the `tryCatch@http://172.16.0.2/container/lib/polyfill.js:6151:37` line? I guess polyfill.js catches everything